# Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process WHEN open the new project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I am new to Android development and Java but after successfully installing Android Studio and the JDK, managing to create my first app and test it both in the emulator and on a phone now whenever I open Android Studio I get the following Message:

Gradle sync failed: Unable to start the daemon process. This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon. For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used. Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/3.3/userguide/gradle_daemon.html Please read the following process output to find out more: ----------------------- Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) 
I have searched this site and extensively on Google and so far all suggested solutions I have found have failed.

I am using Android Studio 2.3.3 and JDK 1.8.0_131.

So far I have tried:-
Uninstalling both Android Studio and the JDK, deleting any folders left behind and then re-installing both.

Deleting the .gradle folder from C:Users$username$.
Changing the Build Process Heap Size to 1024.
Invalidating all caches and restarting multiple times.
Double checking and even Triple checking the paths to the JDK and Android SDK.
Ensuring that I have no extra open programs/windows and background apps in case it was a memory shortage issue suggested in some posts.
I am still at a loss as to how to fix this problem and open to any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: check your jdk and android studio version both should be 32 bit or 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

Go to

1: File > Project structure > SDK Location

2: Check embedded java

and restart android studio